# Network error occurs when Node.js SDK sends peer transactions

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I' m using Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.3 with the following conditions.

- Ubuntu 18.04
- CouchDB
- Raft
- TLS enabled
- Using discovery service
- Endorsement policy: "AND ('Org0MSP.peer')"

When I send 100 transactions asynchronously from Node.js SDK, all transactions are processed normally.
But, I send 2000 transactions asynchronously, the following error occurs.

[Node.js SDK log]

```
[DiscoveyEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G0:0 - endorsement failed - Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL::grpcs//peer0.org0:7051
```

[Peer log]

```
[core.com] SerdrHandshake -> ERRO TLS handshake failed with error read tcp {org0 peer ip address:port} -> {Node.js SDK server ip address:port}: i/o timeout server=PeerServer remoteaddress={Node.js SDK server ip address:port}
```

So, some transactions failed.
Why does this error occur? Is there any way to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'asynchronously' I assume you mean 'concurrently'.  The error being returned is an `i/o timeout`, so this would indicate to me that most likely, your server hardware is not fast enough to handle the volume of concurrent requests you are attempting.

If you are concerned about denial of service, you can employ standard techniques for limiting the number of concurrent connections to your peer such as via network proxies.  If you are simply trying to test the throughput bounds of Fabric, I would try slowly ramping up your transaction rate until you begin to see errors such as this timeout.